# include in include

Tags: php, dom

I have some problem in my PHP code.

I have 3 files:

```
./foo1.php
<?php include './temp/foo2.php'; ?>
_________________________________________
./temp/foo2.php
<?php include '../php/print.php' ; ?>
_______________________________________
./php/print.php
<?php echo 'foo!'; ?>
```

Of course if I go to ./foo1.php nothing will be printed (I want 'foo!') but if I go to ./temp/foo2.php 'foo!' will be printed (it is ok). Problem would be solved when PHP would be including phpfiles in recursive mode... My question is how can I solve this ?

**Update:** this is the solution:

`$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` -> using absolute path before

Comment: what is your directory structure for the 3 files?

Comment: you're using relative paths. If you're running the script from different start-up directories, then yeah, it won't work because relative paths will be relative to the WRONG base directory.

Comment: There is no recursion – there is no recursion…

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This isn't because PHP needs to include files "recursively". From the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php)'s comments:

> Remember that if file A includes file B, and B includes file C; the include path in B should take into account that A, not B, is the active working directory.

Your working directory is `.` and you are including `../php/print.php` via `foo2.php`, which cannot be found. By the way, if you check your logs, you'll see a warning is issued.

To fix this correctly, use a base path, from where you include everything, e.g.:

```
define("BASE", "/var/www/html");

include(BASE."/temp/foo2.php");
include(BASE."/php/print.php");
```

This way, your code is also easily relocatable.

Comment: `Remember that if file A includes file B, and B includes file C; the include path in B should take into account that A, not B, is the active working directory.` It is correct if I want want only operate on file A, but I want operate on A and B both

Comment: @JanQ I do not understand  what you mean with "operate". This is how `include` works, and it is the reason your call fails. If you want to successfully include `print.php` from both files, you have to use absolute paths. For example in the way I described.

Comment: Yes, absolute paths is working (logical). Why if u made `$BASE='/var/www/html' ` it had not worked?

Comment: @JanQ that works as well, but I usually use a define for these. It isn't a variable after all. This way, you don't need `global` in functions/classes and you cannot assign another value to it: http://php.net/manual/en/language.constants.php

Answer (score 1):

PHP handles nested includes just fine.

The problem is that you are providing relative paths, and the current directory of the process (which the paths are relative to) doesn't change depending which file you are in at the time.

There is no problem with relative paths, and there is no problem with multiple entry points (i.e. invoking each of the scripts directly). You *do* have a problem if you try to mix these without taking proper care as you have found out.

If you don't need multiple entry points then simply forget about invoking anything other than one single script directly and make the paths relative to that script's directory.

If you do need multiple entry points then each script will have to be somehow able to detect its position inside your application root and construct relative paths accordingly.